# Trouble loading images from relative paths in Nuxt.js 3

Tags: vuejs3, relative-path, nuxtjs3

I'm currently developing an application using Nuxt.js 3, and I have an array of objects that contains information about team members. Each object has a `profil_path` property that holds the relative path to a profile image.

I want to display these profile images in an `img` tag in my template, but I'm having trouble loading the images correctly.

When I use the :src="people.profil_path" syntax in the img tag, the images fail to load correctly. The URL of the displayed image in the browser's inspector is incorrect, and it uses the relative path instead of the absolute URL.

I tried using require, but Nuxt3 doesn't seem to appreciate it.

```html
<template>
  <div class="card-box my-8 flex flex-wrap justify-between items-center px-4">
    <div v-for="people in team" :key="people.name" class="card m-auto mb-4 p-4 bg-white border rounded-md w-full md:w-1/2 lg:w-1/3 xl:w-1/4">
      <img class="object-cover" :src="people.profil_path" :alt="`Photo of ${people.name}`">
      <p>{{ people.name }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      team: [
        {
          name: "John Doe",
          title: "",
          arts: "",
          palmares: "",
          profil_path: "@/assets/img/profil-placeholder.jpg"
        },
        // ... other team objects
      ]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: have you considered using the [image module](https://nuxt.com/modules/image) / [Documentation](https://v1.image.nuxtjs.org/components/nuxt-img/#usage)?

Comment: I might have missed something in the documentation, but it seems to me that it's complicated to pass it a dynamic path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So ultimately, the solution of using the public folder was a bit bothersome for me, and it also didn't work in production. Therefore, I went back to my assets folder and used regular imports for the images I want to display dynamically.

```
import placeholder from '@/assets/img/profil-placeholder.webp';
import johnDoeProfil from '@/assets/img/jdprofil.webp';
```

Answer (score 1):

Nuxt.js 3 allows serving files from the public directory via a specific app URL. However, it does not serve files from the asset directory and does not make them accessible through public URLs within the app.

To serve locally hosted files using Nuxt, you need to place the files in the public folder and access them as example `/img/profil-placeholder.jpg` path.
Check out [assets directory](https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/assets#assets-directory).